# Sqlite query and alphabetical sort when OnButtonClick in Gridview

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

the title of the question is kinda confusing but i wil try to explain my Problem.

Im programming an Android App, which has 4 Activites. One of them shows a GridView with Buttons. This Buttons text is set to (A,B,C,D,E so on till Z). When i click a Button my new Activity appears. In this activity im trying to show the user a list with words from my database. My Problem is: it doesnt matter if i press the button "A" or "Z" the query ind ButtonOnclickActivity gives me allways teh whole list of the words. Is there a way to tell the query to pick the words when the button example "A" is pressed.

I would like to give you my Code but im getting errors here that my code is not properly formatted as code to upload here ????!!!!

Please help me out =(!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do your query like this

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE 'a%' order by field

Replace table, field and 'a%' for what you need.

Edit

this is what you need.

```
public Cursor getEmployees(String startwith) 
{ 
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase(); 
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder(); 
    String[] sqlSelect = { "0 _id", "Wort", "Erklärung" }; 
    String sqlwhere = " field like '" + startwith + "%'"; 
    String sqlTables = "GlossarKomplett"; 
    qb.setTables(sqlTables); 
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, sqlwhere, null, null, null, null); 
    c.moveToFirst(); 
    return c; 
}
```

Comment: Hello nicolas, ty for your quick answer. But i dont have such a a hardcode for my query here is how i all of my words: public Cursor getEmployees() {

  SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
  SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

  String[] sqlSelect = { "0 _id", "Wort", "Erklärung" };
  String sqlTables = "GlossarKomplett";

  qb.setTables(sqlTables);
  
  Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);

  c.moveToFirst();
  return c;

 }

Comment: You need to stablish the String's start, Try with this.         public Cursor getEmployees(String startwith) 
{ 
 SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase(); 
 SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder(); 
 String[] sqlSelect = { "0 _id", "Wort", "Erklärung" }; 
 String[] sqlwhere = { " field like '" + startwith + "%'" }; 
 String sqlTables = "GlossarKomplett"; 
 qb.setTables(sqlTables); 
 Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, sqlwhere, null, null, null, null); 
 c.moveToFirst(); 
 return c; 
}

Comment: When im trying it returns this at "Cursor c = qb.query" query is red underlined.  The method query(SQLiteDatabase, String[], String, String[], String, String, String) in the type SQLiteQueryBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (SQLiteDatabase, String[], String[], null, null, null, null)

Comment: sorry, my mistake, change the line String[] sqlwhere, for String sqlwhere;

Comment: String sqlwhere = { " field like '" + startwith + "A%'" }; this part is red underlined with the except: "{ " field like '" + startwith + "A%'" }" Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String =( -_-

Comment: db = new MyDatabase(this);
  begriffe = db.getEmployees(); 

  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, begriffe,
    new String[] { "Erklärung" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);

  getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
  inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);       This is how i call getEmployee in my ButtonOnClickActivity is there something wrong maybe? ty alot for your help dude

Comment: public Cursor getEmployees(String startwith)... this method is expecting for a string which is the start letter, for the query, you must to send the "startwith", so your call must be like this 
begriffe = db.getEmployees("a"); or begriffe = db.getEmployees("b"), change for your needs.

Comment: String sqlwhere = { " field like '" + startwith + "A%'" }; this part is still red underlined with the except: "{ " field like '" + startwith + "A%'" }" Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String

Comment: Ok, change for this... String sqlwhere = " field like '" + startwith + "A%'";

Comment: 09-23 13:29:11.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27496): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 13:29:11.469: E/AndroidRuntime(27496): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kidapp3/com.example.kidapp3.ButtonOnClickActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: field (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT 0 _id, Wort, Erklärung FROM GlossarKomplett WHERE ( field like 'AA%')
now when im trying the app crashes with this on the logcat.

Comment: String sqlwhere = " field like '" + startwith + "%'";  Change the word "field" for the field name on your table, the field you are trying to order by.

Comment: 09-23 13:39:12.869: E/AndroidRuntime(28732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 13:39:12.869: E/AndroidRuntime(28732): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kidapp3/com.example.kidapp3.ButtonOnClickActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "'aA%'": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT 0 _id, Wort, Erklärung FROM GlossarKomplett WHERE ( Wort 'aA%')
dude im really sry takiny your time if you cant or dont want to reply its ok im really hopeless right now

Comment: Do you really have a white space in your field name?? "0 _id" i think there is a mistake in this field name.

Comment: sry if im to stupid for this but what is a white space? i changed the field name to _id and tried to launch the app with the code before we started. it still working and listing all words from "Wort". but when im trying to launch it with your suggestion it crashes. you want to look into the code? i have teamviewer if you want

Comment: Ok, give me your team viewer user id and pass

Comment: 205 105 333  pw: 7426